# C++ как добавить префикс '0x' к Hex переменной лежащей в контейнере

Tags: c++, vector, hex, byte, bytearray

У меня имеется контейнер с исходными hex-данными без префикса:

```
vector<uint8_t>package{ 3d, d0, 82, f6, 2f, 65, 0, 81, 2, 34, cc, 70, 3, c0, bc, 83, 60 }
```

Как при извлечении преобразовать их в такой формат, чтобы перед каждым байтом стоял префикс '0x' и записать их в массив unsigned char data.

```
const unsigned char data[] = { 0x3d, 0xd0, 0x82, 0xf6, 0x2f, 0x65, 0x0, 0x81, 0x2, 0x34, 0xcc, 0x70, 0x3, 0xc0, 0xbc, 0x83, 0x60 };
```

Спасибо

Comment: Как вы хотите в байт уместить 4 символа?

Comment: Я кажется разобрался, разницы между 3d и 0x3d никакой. Это все равно одно и тоже десятичное число. Достаточно просто сделать преобразование к (int) или обратно.

Comment: Неправильно вы разобрались. Код `vector<uint8_t> package{ 3d, d0, 82, f6, 2f, 65, 0, 81, 2, 34, cc, 70, 3, c0, bc, 83, 60 };` не компилируется. Префикс числа 0x используется в исходном коде чтобы сказать компилятору, что число записано в шестнадцатиричном формате. Т.е. можно написать вот так `vector<uint8_t> package{ 0x3d, 82};` - одно число записано в шестнадцатиричном формате, второе - в десятичном.

Comment: И числа `0x82` и `82` - разные числа.

Comment: uint8_t = unsigned char. Это одно и тоже.

Comment: Это не одно и то же. Это два разных типа данных, занимающих в памяти 1 байт. И да - их можно приводить одно к другому без потери информации.